# PHP fSockOpen query to server?

Tags: php, sockets, remote-server

I've recently got into **getting data from servers**. For example, from a **CoD 4 server**. Ok?

Now the following, a script I can query the server for status. Meaning, the server's settings (maps, title) and the players with their scores. Now the question is, using a handshake in the fwrite function, what do these mean and how can I, if there is any, get more info out of it?

I am using **"\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFFgetstatus\x00"** to handshake with a CoD 4 server, but I am only getting the player's name, score and ping. What I need is the score, kills, deaths and assists. The point is, are these options/data available and up for grabs or not? I tried many things but I cant seem to get it to work in any other way.

The current script, rescripted from an other class:

```
set_time_limit(5);
$socket = fsockopen('udp://ip:port', 'port', $error, $errorStr, 3);
fwrite($socket, "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFFgetstatus\x00");
$data = fread($socket, 4096);
fclose($socket);
```

This gets me a lot of data, but not enough. My idea is to query a Left 4 Dead server, but I can't even seem to get any data out if it. I do get a resource stream when printed out the $socket.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whats about

```
while( $data = fread( $socket, 4096 ) ) {
    var_dump( $data ); // or something to test output
    ...
}
```